# In symfony2 to make common application library class?

Tags: symfony

I newby in symfony2. I want to make common application library class to use in all application
I created new file AppUtils.php in Admin\FeatureBundle\Repository\ directory with definition

```
<?php
namespace Admin\FeatureBundle\AppUtils;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class AppUtils {
...
```

But in Controller

```
use Admin\FeatureBundle\Repository\AppUtils;

class FeatureController extends Controller
{

    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AdminFeatureBundle:Feature')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Feature entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new FeatureType(), $entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $data= AppUtils::AddSystemParameters( $data, $this, true );
      echo '<pre>$data::'.print_r( $data, true ).'</pre><br>';
...
```

I get Error:

```
The autoloader expected class "Admin\FeatureBundle\Repository\AppUtils" to be defined in file "/mnt/diskC_XP/wamp5/www/wavendon-tenants/src//Admin/FeatureBundle/Repository/AppUtils.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

How to fix it? If there is a better way to make common application library class ?

Comment: You have to use service for that. Check http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
<?php
namespace Admin\FeatureBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class AppUtils {
```